# How to use Monitoring Agent for Datalab Instance

Tags: google-cloud-datalab, google-cloud-monitoring

I need to monitor all our Datalab instances. I know by using [Monitoirng Agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/) we can monitor VMs with many metrics and i need to install it on the instances.

Is it possibile to install it on the Datalab vm as it is a Chromeos vm ?

if yes, how ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

It has been answered on this [Datalab GitHub issue](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1925#issuecomment-359886257):

> The monitoring agent does not currently support the Container-Optimized OS that is used by Datalab. https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/#supported_operating_systems
>
> Even without the agent, Stackdriver will still pull CPU, Disk, and Network usage from the VMs, you just don't get the other metrics , most of which aren't applicable to Datalab. You'll miss out on RAM, swapfile usage, and individual process metrics.
>
> I think the only way around this currently would be to run the Datalab Docker container on a non-ContainerOS image, which would mean writing your own VM startup script.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Stackdriver Monitoring Agent on Container OS VM Instances, just run this command (and restart it) in order to enable the monitoring agent:

`gcloud compute instances add-metadata instance-name --metadata=google-monitoring-enabled=true`